# Call to undefined function geoip

Tags: php, linux, geoip

I installed PHP 5.4 and GeoIP but I can't get the GeoIP to work.
the error is:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_country_code_by_name() in /var/www/html/geoip/test.php on line 7**

This is the script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//$gi = geoip_open( "GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_name('www.example.com');
if ($country) {
    echo 'This host is located in: ' . $country;
}
?>
```

I installed PEAR/PECL still nothing.

is there a log error for geoip or something that can help with is issue?

also I installed GeoIP with PHP 5.3 and it works fine. the problem is with PHP 5.4

Thanks.

Comment: You have not installed it correctly then. How did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mis-configuration or you are giving the function name wrong. To check that it's successfully installed/active;

```
if (function_exists("Function_Name_Here")) {
  echo "Function Does Exist";
} else {
  echo "Function Does Not Exist";
}
```

If this function "does not exist" then re-trace through your installation steps of consult the official manual of this extension for exact installation instructions.

Comment: I installed GeoIP-1.5.0.tar.gz then yum install php-pear and yum install pecl

Comment: how can I check the configuration of geoip ?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_country_code_by_name()

Comment: Have you installed the correct librAry to match your PHP revision?

Comment: I'am not sure, how can I check it?

Comment: anyway does anybody knows how to install jeoip to php5.4 ?

Comment: I installed a new server wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-5*.rpm epel-release-5*.rpm